# Solve $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^2}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{\frac{5}{2}}}.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^2}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{\frac{5}{2}}}.$

**My attempt**

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^2}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{\frac{5}{2}}}.$

$\implies \left(x^2+y^2\right)^{\frac{5}{2}}dy-y^2dx =0$

Given equation is not homogeneous, so, we can't solve using homogeneous method.
Given equation is not total derivative form. So, that method won't be applicable.

Comparing with $Mdx+Ndy=0$

I checked whether the equation is exact or not, I found $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} \neq \frac{\partial M}{\partial y}. $

Can you please help me?
Thank you.

Comment: WolframAlpha offers a solution [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dy%2Fdx+of+%28y%5E2%2F%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%5E%285%2F2%29)

$$\frac{dy}{dx}\bigg(\frac{y^2}{\sqrt{(x^2 + y^2)^5}}\bigg)
 = -\frac{5 x y^2}{\sqrt{(x^2 + y^2)^7}}$$

Comment: @poetasis this is not what the question is asking. The question is asking for the solution to the DE, not the differential.

Comment: @Rhys Hughes Thanks.  I'm not versed enough to understand much of this.

Comment: Are you able t convert to polar coordinates? Or make the substitution y=tx?